# Batch Modification of Text File - grab one value, paste another automatically

Tags: xml, text, vbscript, batch-file, replace

I have a text file that is being processed as part of a batch script for storage in a Document Management System. It's similar to an XML, but slightly different (some proprietary format).
Anyways, My text file looks like this:

```
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:PDF]
[S:WORM]
[C0:20110331]
[C1:AC7100P]
[C2:ACH FILE EDIT LISTING]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\COLD\PROC\AC7100P.PDF
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:PDF]
[S:WORM]
[C0:20110331]
[C1:AT4550P]
[C2:ATM AP MAINTENANCE REPORT BY TIME]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\COLD\PROC\AT4550P.PDF
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:PDF]
[S:WORM]
[C0:20110331]
[C1:CD1640P]
[C2:CD TRIAL BALANCE]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\COLD\PROC\CD1640P.PDF
```

What I need is a vbscript or similar that can look into the file and wherever it sees the C0 value - which will always be a YYYYMMDD formatted date value, it will add a D value with the same date, only MMDDYYYY formatted.
Like this:

```
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:PDF]
[S:WORM]
[D:03312011]
[C0:20110331]
[C1:AC7100P]
[C2:ACH FILE EDIT LISTING]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\COLD\PROC\AC7100P.PDF
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:PDF]
[S:WORM]
[D:03312011]
[C0:20110331]
[C1:AT4550P]
[C2:ATM AP MAINTENANCE REPORT BY TIME]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\COLD\PROC\AT4550P.PDF
[BREAKDOC]
[Y:PDF]
[S:WORM]
[D:03312011]
[C0:20110331]
[C1:CD1640P]
[C2:CD TRIAL BALANCE]
[ENDBREAK]
C:\COLD\PROC\CD1640P.PDF
```

Is this something that could be done with a simple vbscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%a in (%1) do (
 set c=%%a
 set c0=!c:~1,2!
 if .!c0!==.C0 (
   set yyyy=!c:~4,4!
   set mm=!c:~8,2!
   set dd=!c:~10,2!
   echo [D:!mm!!dd!!yyyy!]
 )
 echo !c!
)
```

for more information, read `HELP SET`

Comment: Excellent...this worked perfectly. I was able to simply make a second "createdate" bat that I called within my already existing batch file. Thanks a lot!